# Codeigniter login 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, frameworks, http-status-code-404

I just started working with CI and I'm trying to make an login. I have read a few tutorials and then tried to make one myself but it doesn't work. When i try to login ig get an error:

> The requested URL /Helptor/login_controller/going_in was not found on this server.

I've tried many things but nothing worked.

**This is the login form in my login view:**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>login_controller/going_in" method="post" name="going_in">
<?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?>
<table style="font-size: 30px;">
    <tr>
        <td>Username: </td>
        <td><input type="text" size="45" name="username" style="background-color: #C5D2F5;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td><input type="password" size="45" name="password" style="background-color: #C5D2F5;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" style="border-width: 2px; height: 40px; width: 120px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 22px; background-color: #FEFEFF;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="?lang=en"><img src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/img/United_Kingdom(Great_Britain).png"/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="?lang=nl"><img src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/img/Netherlands.png"/></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Login_controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class login_controller extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index($msg = NULL){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}

public function going_in(){
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->login_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
        redirect('user');
    }        
  }
}
?>
```

**Login_model:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function validate(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

    // Pre ping the query
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    //check for results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        //create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'id' => $row->ID,
                'username' => $row->Username,
                'level' => $row->Level,
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

**Base_url:**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Helptor/';
```

**Index_page:**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Uri_protocol:**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**Update**

My .htaccess file in the map application looks like this

> Deny from all

**Update 2**

This is my folder structure:

```
localhost/helptor
 -application
   -controllers
     -index.html
     -login_controller.php
     -user.php
   -models
     -login_model.php
     -index.html
   -views
     -.htaccess
     -index.html
     -login.php
     -user.php
   .htaccess
   index.html
 -assets
 -system
 index.php
```

Comment: please change your base path only to "/Helptor/"

Comment: Is the htaccess (or similar) correct?

Comment: Can you post the htaccess file

Comment: please make empty your .htaccess file for a while

Comment: Changed my base path to only "/Helptor/", but still getting the same error.

Comment: Is your mod_rewrite switched to on?

Comment: Yes my mod_rewrite is on

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in www/helptor try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /helptor/index.php/$1 [L]
```

You should remember to remove this "helptor" string in future when you deploy to another server.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it is a little too late, but this is that worked for me.

You should set Apache AllowOverride policy to all.
This is what i added to my .conf for the site.

```
<Directory "/var/www/yoursite">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick read of the CodeIgniter docs (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) points one to this `.htaccess` syntax they recommend for their URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Try this and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Tried it, still getting the error. but my .htaccess file is in the application folder, do I have to put it in the views folder?

Comment: You need to put the `.htaccess` in the same folder as the Codeigniter `index.php` file.

Comment: Added my folder structure

Comment: So the `.htaccess` file is within your `Helptor` folder at the root?

Comment: Yes it was but I deleted because when I pressed the login button it went to the localhost page from wamp, which was very strange. It is now only in the views folder and the application folder.